# Why isn't the leading character vanishing as I remove it from the HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, string, substring

I have a div with id="cmdInput" that holds text: "_", and an EventListener:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
  if (evt.keyCode >= 65 && evt.keyCode <= 90) {
    let command = document.getElementById("cmdInput").textContent;
    let str2 = command.substring(0, command.length - 1) + evt.key + "_";
    console.log(str2);
    document.getElementById("cmdInput").textContent = str2;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="cmdInput">_</div>
```

With that code present in my HTML file I load it in Firefox I type "a" and afterwards "b". As a result I get: "_ab_"
But I should get: "ab_"

And here is the questen: Why isn't the leading underscore vanishing as of my typing?

Edit: StackOverflow was cutting my leading underscore. Review my result for what I really get.

Comment: your snippet works as expecting, can you explain more your problem ?

Comment: You _do_ get `ab_` as you can see from the snippet. _"And here is the questen: Why isn't the leading underscore vanishing as of my typing?"_: I thought the point was that you didn't want it to vanish?

Comment: I'm indeed getting "\_ab_", don't know why.